# How do you call a function using jQuery and REST when working with WebAPI2?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have created a "controller" in my WebAPI2 project, and I am able to do basic CRUD operations on the database.  I am now trying to call a controller function that triggers some back-end processing.  How would you call this controller function using jQuery AJAX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How would you call this controller function using jQuery AJAX?

You could use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function in jQuery in order to make AJAX calls:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/resource',
    type: 'PUT',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

There are also shortcuts like [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) that might be worth checking but usually they provide you with less control over the actual request such as setting specific request headers.

Of course if the website containing the javascript that is going to consume your Web API is hosted on a different domain you should read about the [`same origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restriction that's built into the client browsers and which will basically prevent you from making cross domain AJAX requests. The *official way* to make cross domain AJAX calls is to enable [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) support on your API. I will not go into the technical details about how you could enable CORS in your Web API because there are already gazillions of resources available on this subject. [`Here's one`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) on the official ASP.NET website that you might find interesting.